# Direct2D equivalent 2D graphics API for WindowsXP

Tags: visual-c++, animation, graphics

As you all know, Direct2D can be used for 2D animation in case of Windows7.
Since Direct2D is not supported in WindowsXP, can you specify some equivalent 2D graphics API that is supported both in Windows7 and WindowsXP

Answer (score 4):

SDL.
check out http://www.libsdl.org/

It's what i've used for simple top down games and such, very very easy to learn!

Comment: Ok.. I will look into SDL. But Whats the main difference between OpenGL and SDL?

Comment: I couldn't tell you the exact differences, but I believe OpenGL uses 3rd Party libraries for sound, keyboard input, etc... but SDL has it built in. Plus I think SDL is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You may check out agge - https://github.com/tyoma/agge.
It's a CPU-only rendering engine that beats Direct2D in the cases it supports.
The library is limited at the moment, it doesn't support textured/gradient filling, but otherwise is quite simple to use and has STL-lite spirit (in the sense it's more a set of algorithms than a fat interface like GDI's HDC or ID2D1RenderTarget).
Since it's CPU only, it's a cross-platform solution (samples can be compiled for Windows/Mac/Android/ Linux (there's no support for X11 XImage as underlying surface yet)).